# Exclude page number from list in glossaries for some references of that entry

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries, glossaries-extra, back-referencing

Is there a way to specify a glossary entry to generate a reference, but not add its position to the location list in the final glossary? I am trying to do some cross-references like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[autoseeindex=true]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{name=latex, description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents often used by \glspl{mathematician} to typeset \glspl{formula}},
see={formula,mathematician}
}
\newglossaryentry{mathematician}
{name=mathematician, description={person who does maths}}
\newglossaryentry{formula}
{name=formula, description={A mathematical expression}}

\begin{document}
The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for technical documents which need a lot of \glspl{formula}.
\clearpage
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: current behaviour]

Where the references to `formula` and `mathematician` in the `latex` entry show up in the location list behind their respective entries in the glossary, and I would like them not to. I am aware that there exist a starred version `\gls*` which does not add the crosslink but adds its position to the list. I need a command for the "opposite" (for some definition of opposite) behaviour: adding a link, but not adding its location to the list.

something like `\gls[noindex=true]{mathematician}` breaks automatic indexing with `see`, and does not make the entry show up when not using the `see` key. Something like `\gls[format=glsignore]{mathematician}` works somewhat fine, but breaks when actually referencing from the main text, I get this spurious comma showing up. Ideally, I want whatever `autoseeindex` does, but manually.